# Why does interface IEnumerable return IEnumerator GetEnumemrator()? Why not just implement interface IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, interface

For example:

```
public interface IEnumerable
{
     IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}

//This interface allows the caller to obtain a container's items.
public interface IEnumerator
{
bool MoveNext ();
object Current { get;}
void Reset();
}
```

Why not just implement IEnumerator instead of using IEnumerable that forces you to implement a method that returns type IEnumerator?

Comment: Why do we have a shop where you can buy a hammer? Why not just own a hammer? ;o)

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with my C# skills. I am just generously curious as to why. It bothers me... lol

Comment: @SirRufo can you please elaborate? You have a great reputation and I would like to know..

Comment: The IEnumerable interface tells other classes that this class can be enumerated.

Comment: From an IEnumerable you can get an IEnumerator and each IEnumerator can have a different state (current position). - In a shop you can buy as many hammers as you like and do not have to share a single hammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the differences at [this very nice article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/ienumerable-vs-ienumerator-in-C-Sharp/)

TL;DR - Effectively, the `IEnumerable` contract assumes that you have a way of maintaning the state of the Enumerable.

> **Similarities**
>
> Both of these interfaces help to loop through the collection.
>
> **Relation**
>
> The IEnumerable interface actually uses IEnumerator. The main reason to create an IEnumerable is to make the syntax shorter and simpler.
>
> If you go to the definition of the IEnumerable interface, you will see this interface has a method GetEnumerator() that returns an IEnumerator object back.
>
> **Differences**
>
> The main difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerator is an IEnumerator retains its cursor's current state.

When to use:

> So, if you want to loop sequentially through the collection, use an IEnumerable interface else if you want to retain the cursor position and want to pass it from one function to another function then use an IEnumerator interface.

Example:

```
static void iEnumeratorMethodOne(IEnumerator<string> i)  
{  
   while(i.MoveNext())  
   {  
      Console.WriteLine(i.Current);  
  
       if(i.Current == "June")  
       {  
          iEnumeratorMethodTwo(i);  
       }  
    }  
}  
  
static void iEnumeratorMethodTwo(IEnumerator<string> i)  
{  
    while(i.MoveNext())  
    {  
       Console.WriteLine(i.Current);  
     }  
}
```